# Updatepanel gives web request manager error

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am using a radiolist control in my wep page. and there is 3 update panel in that web page. Each update panel contains a list box. All the 3 update panels have a AsyncPostBackTrigger (radiolist index changed event).

my problems is i get an error randomly

```
   Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are internally assigning a string value to the integer data type. In that case you have to use the TryParse method. Please find the code snippet below which may help you

```
int integerValue= 0;

int.TryParse(value, out integerValue);
```

Hope this should resolve your issue.